# Does anyone know what it means to format an LDAP group using LDIF?

Tags: formatting, ldap, ldif

I've set up a group in my companies LDAP directory. However, I've now been tasked with formatting each user using something called LDIF and I can't find anything online about this. Anybody know what this is?

Comment: Perhaps you mean LDIF. RFC2849.

Comment: yes, I meant LDIF. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples of using LDIF at [LDAP: Using ldapmodify](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/) and other posts at my [blog](http://ff1959.wordpress.com).